# How to create a floating JavaScript Clock for UTC and Local Time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I would like to create a rather plain, but attractive clock stylable with css that will float in the upper right corner of a page about 100 pixels down from the top and a 5 pixel margin between the clock's right side and the vertical scrollbar.

I need two clocks: one to display UTC time with a UTC label to the left and a second to display Local Time likewise.

These two clocks should also float so that when you scroll down the page they will become top justified after moving down the page.

*How would I go about creating an arrangement of this nature?  Could you please provide an example of how the code to create this? **jQuery would be fine if simpler.***

*The two clocks may look something like this:*

[image: Two clocks that float right and attach to top on scrolldown]

Comment: The SO community likes it if you post whatever html/script you already have.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case I'm really not sure where to start.  It's a rails 3.1 app with jQuery so my slate is rather blank and thus my open ended question as I'm open to any suggestion for implementation... Including writing a simple script from scratch.

Comment: please see example I whipped up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) here is a script that will fix the container in IE

http://www.gregjopa.com/2011/07/conditional-fixed-positioning-with-jquery/

2) clock plugin
http://www.ajaxupdates.com/jclock-jquery-clock-plugin/
https://github.com/dsparling/jclock

change the jQuery to the latest though

Example - please download the respective sources to your own server:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/RVkEu/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Conditional Fixed Positioning with jQuery</title>

<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#content {
    float: right;
    width: 620px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#right-column {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

#sidenav {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.sidenav-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    width: 288px;
}

#links {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}

h3 {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/dsparling/jclock/master/jquery.jclock.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/master/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/master/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/gist/855078/bf649cd4b0b2df52d3840835c6f7699b79935bab/modernizr-tests.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    if (Modernizr.positionfixed && !Modernizr.appleios && !Modernizr.android) {

        // cache selector queries
        var sidenav = $('#sidenav'),
        sidenavWrap = $('#sidenav-wrap'),
        view = $( window ),
        sidenavHeight = sidenav.outerHeight(true),
        sidenavWrapperOffset = sidenavWrap.offset();

        function horizontalScrollCheck() {
            // update sidenav left position when horizontal scrollbar exists and is scrolled            
            if (view.scrollLeft() > 0) {
                sidenav.css('left', (-1 * view.scrollLeft() + 8));
            }
            else if (sidenav.css('left') != sidenavWrapperOffset.left) {
                sidenav.css('left', sidenavWrapperOffset.left);
            }
        }

        function stickyNavCheck() {

            // apply fixed positioning when sidenav scrolls to the top of the browser and is smaller than viewport height
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > sidenavWrapperOffset.top && view.height() > sidenavHeight){

                if (!sidenav.hasClass('sidenav-fixed') ) {
                    sidenav.addClass('sidenav-fixed');

                    // fill visual space of static positioned sidenav
                    sidenavWrap.css('margin-bottom', sidenavHeight);
                }
                else {
                    horizontalScrollCheck();
                }

            } else {
                if (sidenav.hasClass('sidenav-fixed') ) {
                    sidenav.removeClass('sidenav-fixed');
                    sidenavWrap.css('margin-bottom', 0);
                }
            }       

        }

        // using Cowboy's jQuery throttle/debounce plugin to throttle the scroll event
        view.bind("scroll resize", $.throttle( 100, stickyNavCheck ) );

        // update offset and left position of sidenav on resize event
        view.bind("resize", $.throttle( 100, function() {
                sidenavWrapperOffset = $('#sidenav-wrap').offset();
                if (sidenav.hasClass('sidenav-fixed') ) {
                    horizontalScrollCheck();
                }
            })
        );

    }   


      var options = {
        timeNotation: '12h',
        am_pm: true,
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, Times New Roman',
        fontSize: '20px',
        foreground: 'yellow',
        background: 'red'
      }

  $('#jclock1').jclock(options);

  options["utc"]=true;
  options["utc_offset"]=-1;
  $('#jclock2').jclock(options);


});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Conditional Fixed Positioning w/ jQuery</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="right-column">

        <div id="sidenav-wrap">
            <div id="sidenav">
                <h2>Sticky Clock</h2>
                <p><div class="corner"><div class="jclock"></div></div></p>

<p><div class="nocorner"><div class="jclock"></div></div></p>




                <a href="#">Back to Top</a>
            </div>
        </div>  



    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <h2>Scrollable Content</h2>
        <hr />
        <a id="1"></a>
        <h3>Ut consequat est vitae erat</h3>
        <p>Commoveo wisi nulla pala illum melior quis. Et luptatum validus wisi ingenium humo quidne, eros lucidus dolore ea vel amet. Capto, praemitto singularis tation duis consequat. Jus vulputate ingenium mauris ut, vero. Enim suscipit exerci eligo dolus decet elit transverbero. </p>
        <p>Opto tego, distineo luptatum, amet virtus ideo bene in, vindico eum. Voco, proprius, tation jugis dolore consequat, adipiscing iusto eu, ingenium augue nimis, nostrud, lucidus. Qui tristique uxor ibidem iriure bis praesent os. Consequat zelus pagus abdo augue demoveo odio jus vel. </p>

        <h3>Opto tego, distineo luptatum</h3>
        <p>Commoveo wisi nulla pala illum melior quis. Et luptatum validus wisi ingenium humo quidne, eros lucidus dolore ea vel amet. Capto, praemitto singularis tation duis consequat. Jus vulputate ingenium mauris ut, vero. Enim suscipit exerci eligo dolus decet elit transverbero. </p>
        <p>Opto tego, distineo luptatum, amet virtus ideo bene in, vindico eum. Voco, proprius, tation jugis dolore consequat, adipiscing iusto eu, ingenium augue nimis, nostrud, lucidus. Qui tristique uxor ibidem iriure bis praesent os. Consequat zelus pagus abdo augue demoveo odio jus vel. </p>

        <a id="2"></a>
        <h3>Praesent egestas nulla vel</h3>
        <p>Commoveo wisi nulla pala illum melior quis. Et luptatum validus wisi ingenium humo quidne, eros lucidus dolore ea vel amet. Capto, praemitto singularis tation duis consequat. Jus vulputate ingenium mauris ut, vero. Enim suscipit exerci eligo dolus decet elit transverbero. </p>
        <p>Opto tego, distineo luptatum, amet virtus ideo bene in, vindico eum. Voco, proprius, tation jugis dolore consequat, adipiscing iusto eu, ingenium augue nimis, nostrud, lucidus. Qui tristique uxor ibidem iriure bis praesent os. Consequat zelus pagus abdo augue demoveo odio jus vel. </p>

        <h3>Opto tego, distineo luptatum</h3>
        <p>Commoveo wisi nulla pala illum melior quis. Et luptatum validus wisi ingenium humo quidne, eros lucidus dolore ea vel amet. Capto, praemitto singularis tation duis consequat. Jus vulputate ingenium mauris ut, vero. Enim suscipit exerci eligo dolus decet elit transverbero. </p>
        <p>Opto tego, distineo luptatum, amet virtus ideo bene in, vindico eum. Voco, proprius, tation jugis dolore consequat, adipiscing iusto eu, ingenium augue nimis, nostrud, lucidus. Qui tristique uxor ibidem iriure bis praesent os. Consequat zelus pagus abdo augue demoveo odio jus vel. </p>

        <a id="3"></a>
        <h3>Aenean placerat libero vel</h3>
        <p>Commoveo wisi nulla pala illum melior quis. Et luptatum validus wisi ingenium humo quidne, eros lucidus dolore ea vel amet. Capto, praemitto singularis tation duis consequat. Jus vulputate ingenium mauris ut, vero. Enim suscipit exerci eligo dolus decet elit transverbero. </p>
        <p>Opto tego, distineo luptatum, amet virtus ideo bene in, vindico eum. Voco, proprius, tation jugis dolore consequat, adipiscing iusto eu, ingenium augue nimis, nostrud, lucidus. Qui tristique uxor ibidem iriure bis praesent os. Consequat zelus pagus abdo augue demoveo odio jus vel. </p>

        <a id="4"></a>
        <h3>Morbi viverra lacus pretium</h3>
        <p>Commoveo wisi nulla pala illum melior quis. Et luptatum validus wisi ingenium humo quidne, eros lucidus dolore ea vel amet. Capto, praemitto singularis tation duis consequat. Jus vulputate ingenium mauris ut, vero. Enim suscipit exerci eligo dolus decet elit transverbero. </p>
        <p>Opto tego, distineo luptatum, amet virtus ideo bene in, vindico eum. Voco, proprius, tation jugis dolore consequat, adipiscing iusto eu, ingenium augue nimis, nostrud, lucidus. Qui tristique uxor ibidem iriure bis praesent os. Consequat zelus pagus abdo augue demoveo odio jus vel. </p>

        <a id="5"></a>
        <h3>Ut sit amet orci at magna</h3>
        <p>Commoveo wisi nulla pala illum melior quis. Et luptatum validus wisi ingenium humo quidne, eros lucidus dolore ea vel amet. Capto, praemitto singularis tation duis consequat. Jus vulputate ingenium mauris ut, vero. Enim suscipit exerci eligo dolus decet elit transverbero. </p>
        <p>Opto tego, distineo luptatum, amet virtus ideo bene in, vindico eum. Voco, proprius, tation jugis dolore consequat, adipiscing iusto eu, ingenium augue nimis, nostrud, lucidus. Qui tristique uxor ibidem iriure bis praesent os. Consequat zelus pagus abdo augue demoveo odio jus vel. </p>

        <a id="6"></a>
        <h3>Suspendisse accumsan molestie</h3>
        <p>Commoveo wisi nulla pala illum melior quis. Et luptatum validus wisi ingenium humo quidne, eros lucidus dolore ea vel amet. Capto, praemitto singularis tation duis consequat. Jus vulputate ingenium mauris ut, vero. Enim suscipit exerci eligo dolus decet elit transverbero. </p>
        <p>Opto tego, distineo luptatum, amet virtus ideo bene in, vindico eum. Voco, proprius, tation jugis dolore consequat, adipiscing iusto eu, ingenium augue nimis, nostrud, lucidus. Qui tristique uxor ibidem iriure bis praesent os. Consequat zelus pagus abdo augue demoveo odio jus vel. </p>

        <a id="7"></a>        
        <h3>Praesent scelerisque</h3>
        <p>Commoveo wisi nulla pala illum melior quis. Et luptatum validus wisi ingenium humo quidne, eros lucidus dolore ea vel amet. Capto, praemitto singularis tation duis consequat. Jus vulputate ingenium mauris ut, vero. Enim suscipit exerci eligo dolus decet elit transverbero. </p>
        <p>Opto tego, distineo luptatum, amet virtus ideo bene in, vindico eum. Voco, proprius, tation jugis dolore consequat, adipiscing iusto eu, ingenium augue nimis, nostrud, lucidus. Qui tristique uxor ibidem iriure bis praesent os. Consequat zelus pagus abdo augue demoveo odio jus vel. </p>

    </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks so very much.  Very good job and will dig down into it first thing in the morning and advise as to any hiccups.

Comment: I did throw that together here for convenience and longevity: http://jsfiddle.net/DrjV9/  -- I am not seeing the precise function that I'm assuming you intended off the top so hopefully you might be able to correct that and then throw a working jsfiddle link into the the answer?  I don't think it will much matter, but after you went to all of that effort, I'd love to see the added value of your work in a live example for others to also more fully appreciate.

Comment: I updated it. You did not add the scripts that came with the FIXED postion zip